# what difference between syntax php in php version 5.4.16 dengan 5.2.17?

Tags: php, ckeditor, version, web-hosting

I made my website with php version 5.4.16, but I learning that my hosted sites only support 5.2.17. and it's make trouble with CKEditor, I can't post html or else.

anyone knows the syntax in ver 5.4.16 it doesn's support in ver 5.2.17 ? 
please share what you know. 
thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, our friend Google.com surely knows

Comment: see [new in 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) and [new in 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.php)

Comment: `Please share what you know` ?? Please search what you can, first

Comment: You are probably looking more for function differences eg: function takes x parameters or isn't in x but is in y

Comment: Get your host to upgrade to a supported version of PHP, or change host - there's a lot of new features were introduced in 5.3

Comment: thank all. I've do that.

Comment: Yes, PHP 5.3 is already at it's end of life. Any hosting shouldn't be done with a non-supported version of PHP, and any hoster should be glad to be asked to update a customers account. You also get better PHP performance for free with the update.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Error? Warning? Logs? Come on, we're not fortune telers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing a regression from 5.4 to 5.2, read the list of new features from 5.3 and 5.4. If you are using any of them, you will need to remove them:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

I did a regression like that, and the most painful part was that I had to stop using [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Also, it meant to change from arrays declared like `$a = [1,2];` to `$a = array(1,2);`.

Well, read the links and see how much you'll be missing.